# optimize sed command for better performance

Tags: linux, bash, sed

I have got the following lines in a file:

```
1231231213123123123|W3A|{ (ABCDE)="8=3AF.R.Y2=133AA=9WW=334MNFN=20120925-22:23:59.998
1231231213123123123|4GM|{ (ABCDE)="8=3AF.R.Y2=123AA=9WW=4AF013DCV=EXAMPLE=ABC
1231231213123123123|KYC|{ (ABCDE)="8=3AF.R.Y2=112AA=9WW=0002DDS=20120921-14:55:21
```

In order to get the value between '|' characters I am using:

```
sed -e 's/\(^.*|\)\(.*\)\(|.*$\)/\2/'
```

And output is:

```
W3A
4GM
KYC
```

Which is expected. But as file has thousands of records, sed command is taking a lot of time. Is there any way to improve the performance of this command?

Comment: You could try `awk`, with `awk -F'|' '{print $2}' yourFile`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Seems to me like you just want to use cut:

```
cut -d '|' -f 2 file
```

Set the delimiter to `|` and print the second field.

Answer (score 1):

Since you're only keeping the 2nd parenthesized groups, you're making sed do unnecessary work by remembering the other stuff.  Try

```
sed -e 's/^[^|]*|\([^|]*\)|.*/\1/'
```

Tom Fenech's answer should be a lot faster though.